# Starting PostgreSQL database for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rake, rake-task

I'm trying to get my Rails app connected to a PostgreSQL database.

I successfully ran `rake db:create`

Now when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error ...

```
===============================================================================
HINT:
You might not have the 'pgcrypto' PostgreSQL extension installed.
Install using:

  CREATE extension IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto SCHEMA pg_catalog;

You can also install it in the 'template1' database for future databases.
===============================================================================

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist
LINE 3:           (SELECT gen_salt('bf') AS salt)
                          ^
```

I tried installing the pgcrypto extension, but I get the same error.

I also tried running `rake db:setup` and I get this ...

```
============================================================
WARNING: Pulse calls are disabled until the application is restarted.
rake aborted!
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/kweihe/pmpaware-webapp/db/structure.sql
/Users/kweihe/pmpaware-webapp/lib/tasks/db.rake:8:in `initialize'
/Users/kweihe/pmpaware-webapp/lib/tasks/db.rake:8:in `new'
/Users/kweihe/pmpaware-webapp/lib/tasks/db.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kweihe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:484:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kweihe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/kweihe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:load => db:structure:pg_crypto_preflight
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

*FIXED*

I installed the extension in the wrong db. Went through PgAdmin and installed in correct db, now migrate runs successfully

Comment: What does your `config/database.yml` file look like? You might also want to look at, for example, [How To Setup Ruby on Rails with Postgres](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres)

Comment: Add your fix as an answer and sign it as correct

Answer (score 0):

I installed the extension in the wrong db. Went through PgAdmin and installed in correct db, now migrate runs successfully

Installed extension by running this in the query field:

`CREATE extension IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto SCHEMA pg_catalog;`